# Is there a way for generation of ecdh shared key in 'node-forge' or other checked and secure js oackage

Tags: javascript, ecdsa, ecdh, ed25519, node-forge

Well what i want to obtain is something like this

```
import * as forge from 'node-forge'
const aliceKey = forge.pki.ed25519.generateKeyPair();
const bobKey = forge.pki.ed25519.generateKeyPair();

//get shared secret for bob and alice
function getSharedKey(publicKey, privateKey){
//some code
}

const sharedKeyFromAlicePerspective = getSharedKey(bobKey.publicKey , aliceKey.privateKey);
const sharedKeyFromBobPerspective = getSharedKey(aliceKey.publicKey, bobKey.privateKey);

console.log(sharedKeyFromAlicePerspective === sharedKeyFromBobPerspective)//expect 'true'
```

Also i am open for changing library for other secure and well maintained and tested if its not possible in standard that this library provides (my point is to make smallest possible secure public keys for encryption beetween parties)

Comment: It seems that node-forge does not support ECDH and X25519. An alternative would be NodeJs' crytpo module, see https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-ecdh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well beside @Topaco answear
i found out if you are in browser that support Crypto.subtle api you can do without modules.

```
const aliceKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-521'},false, ['deriveBits']);
const bobKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-521'},false, ['deriveBits']);
const secret = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits({
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-521",
        public: bobKey.publicKey
    },
    aliceKey.privateKey, 
    521
)
```